# Does OpenCL 2.0 Supported in NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

Is it possible to use OpenCL 2.0 in NVIDIA GPUs? It was tough for me to find the list of Supported devices for OpenCL 2.0. I really appreciate it if someone could share it with me.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the full feature set. Nvidia only ever supported OpenCL 1.2 fully and OpenCL 2.0 [partially](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2017-02-22/nvidia-enables-opencl-2-0-beta-support/) (Kepler and newer architectures).

With the most recent driver [466.11](https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/466.11/466.11-win10-win8-win7-release-notes.pdf), Maxwell and newer architectures now support OpenCL 3.0. OpenCL 3.0 basically is OpenCL 1.2 with optional OpenCL 2.x features. Nvidia has added a few new OpenCL 2.x features, but still has no full support.